# Dirichlet Conditions and Fourier Analysis.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I read in my text book that the Dirichlet conditions are sufficient conditions for a real-valued, periodic function $f(x)$ to be equal to the sum of its Fourier series at each point where $f$ is continuous.

However, it further stated that although the conditions are **sufficient but they are *NOT* necessary**.

Why are the Dirichlet conditions "not necessary" ?

Example : One of the Dirichlet conditions state that the function can not have infinite discontinuities. Hence we can not express, a function like $ tan x $  in terms of a Fourier series since (as it appears) violates one of the conditions. So, why is that they are 'not necessary'?

P.S.: The Wikipedia Link to the [Dirichlet conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions).

Comment: $\tan{x}$ is not continuous at the point at which it appears to violate the Dirichlet conditions.

Comment: Yes, that is why we can not express it in terms of Fourier series. It has an infinite discontinuity at pi/2 and hence can not be expanded in the interval -pi to pi. The question is why are the Dirichlet conditions deemed 'NOT NECESSARY'.

Comment: Something like $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$

Comment: I think the confusion stems from the usage of "not necessary" in mathematical writing, which is different from colloquial English. Saying that a condition is *not necessary* does not mean that it's something we can throw out. See [necessity and sufficiency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditions are "not necessary" because no one proved a theorem that if the Fourier series of a function $f(x)$ converge pointwise then the function satisfies the Dirichlet conditions.

Some general information: the issues of the pointwise converges of Fourier series are very delicate matter. As far as I understand we still do not have the exact condition to fully identify the class of functions whose Fourier series converge. It was proved, as @chaohuang pointed in another answer, that if $f\in L^2$, then the Fourier series converge. On the other hand, A. Kolmogorov provided an example of a function $f\in L^1$ whose Fourier series do not converge at *any* point. I am sure you can find much more information on these issues in any serious text on Fourier analysis.

Comment: I also came across the fact that arcsin x has a convergent Fourier series but does not satisfy the Dirichlet conditions.
_The conditions are "not necessary" because no one proved a theorem that if the Fourier series of a function f(x) converge pointwise then the function satisfies the Dirichlet conditions._ makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Another sufficient condition is $f(x) \in \mathbb{L}_2(-\frac{1}{2}L,\frac{1}{2}L)$.

Answer (score 0):

One of the conditions that is not necessary in general to have a Fourier series that converges back to the original function, yet is in Dirichlet's conditions, is that the function has finitely many local maxima/minima.

For instance, if we consider $f(x) = x^n\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ on $[-\pi, \pi]$ for $n \geq 3$, we see that $f$ is ${\mathcal C}^1$ and hence its Fourier series converges to $f$. Also, to make $f$ have any degree of smoothness, we can just make $n$ sufficiently large.

So, we see that $f$ has a Fourier series that converges to $f$, yet has local minima/maxima at $x = \frac{1}{(2k + 1)\pi}$, where $k$ is an integer.